# Change color of html.actionlink based on db data

Tags: c#, css, asp.net-mvc

This question has been asked before, but I am not able to style my actionLink with all those solution.

What I need  is :
if the value of "generate" is 1 I need the Generate actionLink as red else green.

view:

```
 @Html.ActionLink("Generate", "Generate", new { id = item.Session_id, @class = "generate_link " })
```

style.css:

```
.generate_link {
    color:darkred;
}
```

I tried including class but it is not working.

Comment: can you provide a sample of your code?

Comment: @Html.ActionLink("Generate", "Generate", new { id = item.Session_id, @class = "generate_link " })

Comment: css:       generate_link a{
    color:darkred;
}

Comment: even this class is not taken.

Comment: @Html.ActionLink("Generate", "Generate", null, new { id = item.Session_id, @class = "generate_link " })
try this

Comment: This too not working

Comment: please edit your question and put your whole code here

Answer (score 0):

Just use a ternary(sp?) operator...

```
@Html.ActionLink("Generate", "Generate", new { id = item.Session_id, @class = (Model.Generate == 1 ? "generate_link " : "") })
```

If `Generate` equals one is will assign a class of `generate_link`, if not it will leave blank `""`